# Android activity error - error inflating class Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am at my wits end with this!
I am trying to add a fragment to my activity. I have read plenty of Stackoverflow articles about this error, but none of the solutions I've seen (extending FragmentActivity, importing android.support.v4, etc, etc) have fixed it for me.

This is the error I'm seeing:

```
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/net.myd.app.custom.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Fragment
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class Fragment
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at net.myd.app.custom.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:46)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     ... 11 more
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-21 13:59:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     ... 22 more
```

This is the fragment class I am using:

```
package net.myd.app.custom;

import com.example.myfirstapp.R;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MyFragment extends Fragment 
{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is the activity I'm using:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
    // ... class fields

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_activity);

        selectFragment();
    }

    public void selectFragment()
    {
         Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.my_fragment, fragment);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    // etc...
}
```

And in the xml for my activity, this is how I am referencing the fragment:

(There was one stackoverflow article where it suggested adding the full class path to the fragment xml code, I tried this and that didn't work either).

```
 <Fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If anyone can see any problems that are causing this error, I would be really appreciative!

Thanks

Comment: there is an error in your xml class

Comment: have you used any layout  on fragment????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<Fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

with something like:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: You are a legend. That fixed it!! Thanks. I will be ticking your answer when the 5 minute limit is up :)

Answer (score 0):

Using FrameLayout may fix the problem.

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```